# Adding arrays within loop Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Please need help...

```
$months = Records::select('payment_month')
    ->distinct()->where('payment_year',$year)
    ->where('company_id',$company_id)->get();

foreach ($months as $month) {

    $data = Records::select(
        DB::raw('SUM(record_db.credits) as credits'),
        DB::raw('SUM(record_db.amount) as amount'),
        DB::raw('SUM(record_db.totalamount) as totalamt'), 'record_db.payment_month')
            ->where('record_db.company_id','=',$company_id)
            ->where('record_db.payment_month','=',$month->payment_month)
            ->where('record_db.payment_year','=',$year)
            ->first();
}       

return Response::json($data);
```

The above query works fine and I have the month of `January, February and March` in the database table but it only returns the records of `March`.

I tried `results[]=$data` but still don't work.

Comment: What result do you want to have exactly?

Comment: `January 910 345 657` `February 345 980 123` `March 214 436 989`, something like this...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
$data = Records::select(
    'payment_month',
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.credits) as credits'),
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.amount) as amount'),
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.totalamount) as totalamt')
)->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
->where('payment_year', '=', $year)
->groupBy('payment_month')
->orderBy('payment_month')
->get();

// then
$data->toJson(); // returns something like:
[{"payment_month":"January","credits":"123","amount":"456","totalamt":"789"}, ... ]
```

Comment: Was able to solve it when the site was in read only mode, using `$result[]=$data->toArray()`. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You had override $data array from every month result. You should use whereIn as follows.

```
$months = Records::select('payment_month')
    ->distinct()->where('payment_year', $year)
    ->where('company_id',$company_id)->get();

$monthValues = array();

foreach ($months as $month) {
    $monthValues[] = $month->payment_month;
}

$data = Records::select(
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.credits) as credits'),
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.amount) as amount'),
    DB::raw('SUM(record_db.totalamount) as totalamt'), 'record_db.payment_month')
    ->where('record_db.company_id','=',$company_id)
    ->whereIn('record_db.payment_month', $monthValues)
    ->where('record_db.payment_year','=',$year)
    ->first();
```

Comment: `$monthValues` is returning `null`

Comment: check your $months array. It should null.

Comment: Months array contain `payment_month: January, payment_month: February, payment_month: March`

Comment: So. how $monthValues be null? check print $month array in the loop. Anyway you should to do whereIn. Check it with laravel manual.

Comment: sorry, I was doing a typo but using `whereIn` is giving errors